# Why can you only upload images in chat?

Tags: discussion, support, chat, image

Currently you are unable to upload anything but images in chat, why is this so? Is this because of security or some other reason such as space?

Comment: What else would you upload? The only reason you can post images is that they're visual and can be seen directly in the chat room. What else would you want to upload?

Comment: SE uses https://imgur.com as image hoster - they probably could add other services to host other kinds of data, but what for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can upload whatever you like (to wherever will host it) and post the URL.

The "upload" in the Upload button, however, is just shorthand for "Upload an image". That is made abundantly clear when you click it.

This is exactly the same with the main sites.